# Can I make a boxplot with this data?

Tags: r, boxplot

I am not sure if I have to change the format of my data to make a boxplot.
My data looks like this:

```
Land   Income 1999 Income 2019
Spain    5             7
France   4             8
Greece   3             5
...
```

Now I want to make two box plots to compare the income in 1999 and 2019.
Is that possible?
I don't know how I should choose the axes.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There’s no need to reformat the data, you can create boxplots directly. Assuming your data is in a table called `df`:

```
boxplot(df[, -1L])
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you! I used ggplot and did not know how to choose x and y.

Comment: @WeareR Ah if you’re using ‘ggplot2’ please refer to the other answer — you’ll indeed need to reformat the data, but the solution is more generalisable.

Comment: @WeareR In the future, if you're using a specific package, you should reference that package in the question as well as the tags you chose for your post

Answer (score 1):

An approach with ggplot2:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  country = c("Spain", "france", "Portugal"),
  "income_1999" = c(9,8,7),
  "income_2019" = c(11,10,9)
  
)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-country, names_to = "income", values_to = "amount") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=income, y=amount)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-10-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much! My data contains about 200 countries, so it might be easier to use the not-ggplot solution.

Comment: @WeareR Actually the same code works regardless of numbers of countries.

Comment: ok, I got it now. Thank you for your help!!

Comment: Nice to hear. In order to close the question, you should accept one of the two answers.